# Typescript type predicates not differentiating between equivalent types when apllied to union type

Tags: typescript

Hey I'm trying to differentiate between two equivalent types:

```js
type A = {
    a: string
}

type B = {
    a: string
}
```

With two type predicates:

```js
function isA(obj: any): obj is A {
    return true
}

function isB(obj: any): obj is B {
    return true
}
```

But I'm facing an issue where each predicate catches both types when applied to a union type.

Here is an example: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFTUCGAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOboC+66okUAQgsuljvkWVbfWgBmAV3IBjYKQD25KKQIwAFFIBGAK3zZyIAJT5VauQVjsMWYhGDDisksIj806EeMkyjzZes3a9UA0YsppwWVjZQdg5odE6x6AD08VAA6lLEANbG2MYQAB6QEhAAJuhiMkQREEQA8uoAjD4gbEh4UADkbTQA3OikglCK8krAVcC1anU6OsFYIzX1UIkR4BD4MLRQEAA2BNB9A-Kec2P1UzOYx+N1i0mMqyyOCUkAKitQ5FLA79jExFIA7sVSuUvpd1AAmNZQAA+QUQLXwHW6vX6gwUijBanBZ1QZguo3G4Juy0gUNhzA2212clRhwxBIhOI4swZWOJd3w5AgADcIMRHEA)

Is this the intentional behavior? and if so, what is the use case?

Comment: TypeScript's type system is structural, not nominal. However there are some [ways](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/nominal-typing) to mimic it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just casting to `any` before the `if`, just like the ts playground link I have in the question.
This way I have the union type outside the `if` and the wanted type inside the `if`

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has a structural type system. Two types with the same structure are equivalent. So your `A` and `B` types are essentially equivalent

When you have a type guard, the type in the `is` clause of the guard just is just the base type of what can be guarded. Subtypes can also be guarded out of a union. This means the type in the `is` clause, is not the final type of that might show up but rather the type that each constituent of the union is tested against.

```
type A = {
    a: string
}

type B = {
    a: string
    b: string
}

function isA(obj: any): obj is A {
    return true
}

const testObj2: number | B = {a: '', b: ''};
if (isA(testObj2)) {
    testObj2 // type: B
} else {
    testObj2 // number
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFTUCGAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOboC+66okUAQgsuljvkWVR1gCNuJCtTR006AGYBXcgGNgpAPbkopAjAAUygQCt82ciACU+XXvUFY7DFmIRgM4mpIyItemnmqiUYBBEAPL6AEz45DIAtgIQxFAAPixsSHhQAOTpADRQQhnpNADc6KRSUFoa2gHBYSYmtpzVwCF6oVAA9O3+4BD4zLRQEAA2BNCodphNLW2dUJExcbRAA)

So what happens in your case is that `isA(o: any): o is A` is guarding a variable of type `A | B`. What the compiler asks is:

1. Is `A` from the union assignable to `A` from the `is` clause (yes)
2. Is `B` from the union assignable to `A` from the `is` clause (yes)

Since the answer to both of these is yes, the type on the guarded branch is still `A | B`. And since we handled both cases on the true branch there is nothing left on the `else` branch

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. do you know of any workaround / trick? i would still like to do something different based based on the guard's decision.

Comment: @user16214132 As long as those types are identical or one is a base type of another the behavior will be the same. If you are relying on types to be different just because the name is different that is not the way TS types work, and typically is not the way JS works at runtime either. If you add something like a `__type: "A"` and `__type: "B"` props to the types it will work as expected

Comment: @user16214132 something like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFTUD63SQH4AuKAIhlPSygEMSBnYAJwEsA7Ac3QF9119oAIQTIqWXAOJlBlDFjpRGrTjz5oAZgFc2AY2AsA9mygt6MABQGARgCsSNNiACUJazZP1YouZiYRgmkzGzJoQqmjoWrr6Rh6Clrb2ji5Qbh5Qwqg+UH4BQVAhYWi8EWgA9GVQAOoGTADWnmwGAO7oOkaMBRCMAPK2AEwkcAA+GSJICgDkk9wA3Ogs6lDmphbA3cB9Nv1OTt7U670DUBUF4BBDPFAQADb00IvLpvGHmwO7+1ivW-0nlQIkQThIA